# What is the difference between an Ordered and Unordered Collection in .NET

Tags: .net, collections

I have been learning about collection in .NET, and I have come across the terms, `Ordered` and `Unordered`. I do not know what the difference is between them. Could someone please explain what exactly is the difference, and when one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In mathematical terms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7912/141604), an *ordered* collection is like a sequence, an *unordered* collection is like a set.

In practical terms, you use an ordered collection if, well... order matters, and an unordered collection if it doesn't.

As a concrete example:

- I want to store which file extensions are fine for my file uploading service. I'd use an unordered collection, since I only care whether an entry is in the collection or not. I don't care about the *order*.

  ```
  var imageExtensions = new HashSet<string>() { "gif", "jpg", "png" };

  // I might just as well have written { "jpg", "png", "gif" } -- it doesn't matter
  ```
- I want to store the words of a sentence. The sentence might have duplicate words, and I might want to refer to the "third" word by index number. Here, I use an ordered collection.

  ```
  var words = new List<string>() { "one", "small", "step", "for", "man", "one", "giant", "leap", "for", "mankind" };
  ```

In the .NET base class library, unordered collections are usually optimized for efficiently finding elements of the collection. For example, `HashSet<T>.Contains` is an O(1) operation. On the other hand, finding an element in a `List<T>` requires traversing the list and is, thus, an O(n) operation.